# Is percentage difference or factor-difference better

Tags: percentage

I am doing a study comparing the performance of individuals in reporting the radiation dose of x-rays before and after a teaching session.

I am asking individuals to compare the radiation dose of a given scan to a chest x-ray which is defined as 1 unit.
For example a given radiological scan may expose a patient to 50 units of radiation (the equivalent of 50 chest x-rays)

When analysing the results pre- and post-teaching is it better to consider

1. Absolute difference
2. Percentage difference
3. Difference as a factor

For example:
If the median response from the group (pre-teaching) was 1 CT-chest = 40 units, and the correct answer is 150 units, would it be better to say:

1. Absolute difference = 110 units
2. Percentage difference = 73%
3. Difference as a factor = 3.75

Under and over-estimations of results are equally important.
I am doing a simple pre and post survey of knowledge following a simple teaching session and am looking to see if post-teaching the answers are closer to the correct value, irrespective of whether the answer is an over-estimate or under-estimate. At the moment I am not interest in whether a particular method works better than another; I am just interested to see if people retain this kind of information after a short presentation.

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use the (estimated-actual) difference itself: like -110 units in your example?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure which is better? Is absolute difference, percentage difference or factor-difference more useful for statistical analysis?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more details about the training process and how you would like to organize your eventual results. For example, are there multiple types of images with widely different actual doses? Do you yourself care more about absolute or percentage errors? Does it matter more if the errors are on the high side or on the low side, or are over- and under-estimates equally important? Are you comparing different training methods, just doing a simple pre/post comparison of a single type of training, looking at whether some training methods work better than others...?

Comment: Please see the ammended post

Comment: what does it mean to "consider" a number? Is there decisioning that you are planning on doing based on the numbers? Are you planning on presenting numbers to an external audience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closer you stick to the original values the better, in many cases. If you don't care about the direction of the error but just how close the estimates are to the true value, the absolute value of the error in its original units would be a good choice.

Rather than looking at the change in the median absolute value of the error, as your question suggests, you would get a lot more information by looking at paired within-individual differences, for example with a paired t-test. Then you can get estimates of statistical significance of the change, confidence limits for the change, and so on.

The above assumes that there is just one type of image involved, you provide the training, and then show the same type of image again. Things are a bit more complicated if you are evaluating several different types of images that might have different true dose values, say some 10 units and some 200 units. Then you might be more interested in the relative error, and use the ratio of the absolute error to the true value (relative absolute error) to combine information among different types of images.

Things like percentages and percentage changes can be too easily misinterpreted. See [this page](https://www.fharrell.com/post/percent/) for why simple fractions or ratios are preferable if you can't just use the original scale of units.